# Add table view to the body of email in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiwebview, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

- I was working for a mail app using MFMailComposeViewController.
- web page was loaded when user cliks on a button.
- - i set recipients sender, cc to the mail.
- - i attach one image to the body of email using follow code:

---

```
 [mailpage setToRecipients:toRecipients];
        [mailpage setCcRecipients:ccRecipients];    
        [mailpage setBccRecipients:bccRecipients];

    // Attach an image to the email
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"iCon" ofType:@"png"];
    NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    [mailpage addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"iCon"];
```

---

Now i want to attach the table view which was already in my view to the body of the email page.

help me..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK it's not possible to add UITableView to email. You have two options, first - generate html, and content of table view as html table, or second - render content of this UITableView in PDF file, and next add this pdf to email.

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestions.
let me know how to generate html with content of table view.?
please tell me. im a fresher.

Comment: As Kareem wrote, you need generate html, as set of tags, write it to email using:
    NSString *emailBody = @"<html>....</html>";
    [mailpage setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];

Comment: check it out please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9061479/how-to-create-a-uitableview-in-html-page-to-mail-my-table-view-in-mfmailcompose